# Can DDS be used in OpenGL in Linux without license/patent issue?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, linux

Is there a 'standard' for OpenGL game creation intended for both Windows and Linux? I understand DDS is the DirectX standard (or, at least, it appears to be). Is there one that does not have potential patent/license issue or does it really not matter?

I am asking as I would like to avoid focusing on DDS as the format to use, only to have that kick me in the teeth later when some license/patent/??? issue requires me to remove and replace DDS with *[texture format here]*. This is not about what is better or an opinion post, but what is (relatively) safe from the constraints mentioned earlier?

Comment: Usually you'll target your texture format in your built game to the types that your target rendering hardware supports (eg. [The various S3TC modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) and [BPTC modes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/BPTC_Texture_Compression), for which DDS is just a container). So, do you have a minimum hardware spec you're targeting?

Comment: @DMGregory: Thank you for the reply! Hardware spec minimum is (loosely) dual core 2.4Ghz, ~2GB RAM, and Geforce 8600 / ATI Radeon HD 3450. Building a 2D sidescroller with an excessive number of particles & models (mainly because I'm completely insane). I have been reading on an [older presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/beyond-porting) by nVidia that seems to hold promise for relatively high performance, though it may require *significantly* newer hardware.

Comment: As I reflect on this, it might be useful to clarify whether you're referring to the file format or the texture data format. In many cases they're equivalent (ie. a `.png` image file will have the layout and headers of a Portable Network Graphics file format and contain image data in the PNG predicted & compressed pixel format). But for GPU formats used in games these can differ: we may use different texture data formats depending on the texture's needs and GPU support, but put them all into a standard file format, or even pack them straight into combined "asset blobs" instead of their own file

Comment: @DMGregory, again, thank you for being awesome! I setup basic PNG loading earlier so I had a method to load some form of texture. While it works well enough, I am somewhat concerned that simply using PNG and attempting to programmatically create mipmap levels will end horribly (or hilariously?) with asset blobs or 'mega textures'. My reason for asking about DDS is many resources keep using DDS as the 'go-to' for textures and mipmaps. However, as it is likely apparent, my understanding is not with graphical programming (but rather, os/filesystems/networks/etc).

Comment: The patent on S3 compression expired earlier this year; there are no other licensing or patent issues you need concern yourself with regarding the DDS format.

Comment: Jack, thank you! With that, I have no further questions.

Comment: @JackAidley that looks like it could be fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: @DMGregory: I didn't post it as an answer as it doesn't seem to answer the title question, although given the asker's response above perhaps I will.

Comment: Sometimes the title isn't the best guide. Here, we might be able to edit the title to ask "Can I use DDS files in my OpenGL game?" With the body asking "...or is there a standard alternative?" Does that accurately represent what you needed answered, @BeauB.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disk texture format that is standard for OpenGL, but the DDS data format is relatively easy to read in and use in OpenGL since DDS is essentially a wrapper for compressed textures and the compression format used is supported by OpenGL. Thus you may find DDS suitable for cross-platform development.

The only patent related issue with DDS was with [the S3 compression technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) used, however the patent on that expired earlier this year so there is no possibility of further problems.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the patents on the compression tech needed to be licensed by software/hardware that implemented the decompressor (ie. the graphics cards / drivers that wanted to support displaying textures in that format), not for simply storing texture data in that format. So even while the patent was active I don't think game makers needed to licence the patent for each game. But I am not a lawyer or patent expert so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @DMGregory: I am also not a lawyer but my understanding is that there can be an issue if you either statically link a library or include it with your distribution.